# ngonit/constructor method gets called twice when routing happens

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Demo of the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-routeissue

https://angular4-routeissue.stackblitz.io/4566

I have a route requirement like `localhost:4200/1234` where `1234` is mapped to adNo.

And i have child route like `localhost:4200/ad1` and `localhost:4200/ad2`. landComponent oninit method gets the parameter and decides where it has to redirect internally.

Issue is that oninit method is called twice when page is loaded first i.e when `localhost:4200/1234` is loaded, how can this be prevented.Calling twice happens when navigateByUrl is invoked. Below is the route code

**Root route**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: ':adNo', component: landComponent },
];
```

**Child route**

```
export const subRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: landComponent,
    children: [{ path: 'ad1', component: infoComponent },
    { path: 'ad2', component: typeComponent }]
  }
];
```

**LandComponent**

```
ngOnInit() {    
   // logic to get the adNo and make service call
   this._activatedRoute.snapshot.params['adNo'];
   console.log('working');
   this._router.navigateByUrl('ad1', { skipLocationChange: true });
}
```

Comment: I could see that the call is made **only once**

Comment: Did u try with url paramater ?? https://angular4-routeissue.stackblitz.io/4566

Comment: @Hacker did you try with `pathMatch:"full"` in the child routes?

Comment: @Jai - If i do that the routing    this._router.navigateByUrl('ad1', { skipLocationChange: true });
 does not work

Comment: probably i didn't understand your problem but: in the ngOnInit() there is a call to `this._router.navigateByUrl('ad1', { skipLocationChange: true });`, so the first time you pass in the OnInit you look for query param, then call router. When you change route you pass exactly to the ngOnInit again... of course it's called twice.. have you tried to implement this logic within the constructor?

Comment: @LucaTaccagni - But ad1 is pointing a different component.  landComponent  ngonit is hit twice.

Comment: you are `skipping locantion change`, so you are landing into landComponent again

Comment: Even if locatiochange is true/false same issue